# Firefox audio delay when seeking mp3 file

Tags: html, firefox, mp3, html5-audio

### Context

I am using the `audio` HTML5 tag into a tool that allows accurate actions on audio files.

The audio source is an mp3 file with Constant Bit Rate of 128kbps.

User can seek a given time of the file on demand. I am using the `HTMLMediaElement.currentTime` to perform this action.

### Problem

On firefox, if i try to seek a time close of the beginning (from 0 to 20 seconds approximately), an unexpected behavior happens. The file is played from the given time (I can see the time cursor moving) but there is no sound during a lapse of time (from 0 to 2 seconds)

e.g. if I seek my file at 10seconds. It will play from 10 to 12s without sound and then go on playing with the sound after 12s.

### Reproduction steps

[I created a plunker to reproduce the behavior.](http://plnkr.co/edit/KtfFW83jIz9px49EAYRx?p=preview) You can play the file from begining to confirm that there is sound between 10 and 12s and then seek at 10s using the button to observe the behavior.

### Additional informations

I have tested on both Firefox 56.0 and 57.0.4.
There is no problem on Chrome, IE or Edge.

The problem is not related to the "Accept-Ranges: bytes" header. The problem occurs with and without support for HTTP 206 Partial Content.

Here are the properties of the audio file :

> Audio
>
> Format                         : MPEG Audio
> Format version                 : Version 2
> Format profile                 : Layer 3
> Duration                       : 25 min 6 s
> Bit rate mode                  : Constant
> Bit rate                       : 128 kb/s
> Channel(s)                     : 1 channel
> Sampling rate                  : 22.05 kHz
> Compression mode               : Lossy
> Stream size                    : 22.9 MiB
> Writing library                : LAME3.99r
> Encoding settings              : -m m -V 4 -q 3 -lowpass 11 -b 128

Some files with the same properties do not reproduce the behavior, some does.

Comment: May be related to [Bug 
`<audio>` can't play a local mp3 file from its beginning](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=873898)

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Sad to report this is still an issue 2 yrs later. After seeking there is a delay before audio starts (I've seen up to 4 secs,) yet time updates continue, thus the audio becomes out of sync with time reported by audio.currentTime.  As with you, some files work and some don't, even though they are all created with the same software and config. Files created using LAME, haven't tested on proprietary created files. All tested files work fine on Chrome, so seems like Firefox bug.  Workaround was to convert the files to ogg vorbis using ffmpeg. All the ogg files play fine.

Comment: I confirm that this is still an issue in September of 2020.

Comment: As of 2022, Firefox Developer 102, this issue is fixed

Comment: Not fixed at least on mobile. My version is 102.2.1 (Build #2015891003)